# can't convert string to datetime python

Tags: python

how to convert '2020-08-26T12:09:14+0000' to datetime using python

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '2020-08-26T12:09:14+0000'
f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(s, f)
```

but I got this error:
time data '2020-08-26T12:09:14+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

what's the correct format ?

Comment: Format doesn't match with string. *(delete `.%f` to fix)*

Comment: I don't know the correct format @OlvinRoght

Comment: I've left *a hint* in my previous comment, try to use it.

Comment: thanks it's working with me. @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct format is : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Answer (score 0):

f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f%z'
just take out '.'